# Как правильно сделать POST ajax запрос?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

GET-запрос работает:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET", "search.php?q="+val, true);
            xhr.send();
```

PHP (GET):

```
 header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251");
             if(ISSET($_GET)) {
                 $val = $_GET['q'];
                 echo $val;
             } else {
                 echo 'Not GET variables';
             }
```

POST:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", "search.php", true);
            xhr.send(val);
```

PHP:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251");
         if(ISSET($_POST)) {
             $val = $_POST['val'];
             echo $val;
         } else {
             echo 'Not POST variables';
         }
```

JS полный:

```
var val;
    var inp = document.querySelector("#query-input");
    inp.onkeyup = function () {
        val = inp.value;
        if (val.length != 0) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", "search.php", true);
            xhr.send(val);
        }

    }
```

Не работает POST-запрос. Нет вовсе никакого ответа. Т.е. запрос-то есть, но сервер не отвечает, хотя переменная val определена. Как правильно сделать запрос?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Первое.** Используйте [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) вместо [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php). `isset()` проверяет существование переменной (переменные `$_GET` и `$_POST` существуют всегда), а `empty()` - существует ли переменная и пуста ли она (там много нюансов, уточните их в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)). У вас в PHP-коде конструкция `else` никогда не сработает.

**Второе.** В вашем примере с POST-запросом на JavaScript переменная `val` содержит в себе строку в неправильном формате. Чтобы PHP смог воспользоваться ею, эта переменная должна быть строкой, имеющей формат `foo=bar` (`foo` - имя поля POST-запроса, `bar` - значение поля). То есть в вашем случае переменная `val` должна быть строкой `val=example`, чтобы к ней можно было обратиться в PHP как к `$_POST['val']`. То есть четвертую строку последнего вашего блока кода надо заменить на это:

```
val = 'val=' + encodeURIComponent(inp.value);
```

Советую вам ознакомиться со [статьёй про XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms), где подробно объясняется этот момент.

**Третье.** В PHP используйте функции в нижнем регистре. Не `ISSET()`, а `isset()`.

**Четвертое.** Включите отображение ошибок в PHP. Пропишите это в начале самого первого вызываемого файла:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Из-за того, что у вас PHP не мог найти переменную `$_POST['val']`, он отбрасывал ошибку и прекращал работу, из-за чего ваш скрипт не выводил вам никакой текст.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснение !